# Grep pattern between quotes

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to grep a code base to find alpha numeric codes between quotes. So, for example my code base might contain the line

```
some stuff "A234DG3" maybe more stuff
```

And I'd like to output: A234DG3

I'm lucky in that I know my string is 7 long and only integers and the letters A-Z, a-z.

After a bit of playing I've come up with the following, but it's just not coming out with what I'd like

```
grep -ro '".*"' . | grep [A-Za-z0-9]{7} | less
```

Where am I going wrong here? It feels like grep should give me what I want, but am I better off using something else? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more playing about I've come up with this which gives me what I'm after:

```
grep -r -E -o '"[A-Za-z0-9]{7}"' . | less
```

With the -E allowing the use of the {7} length matcher

Answer (score 0):

Using basic or extended POSIX regular expressions there is no way to extract the value between the quotes with `grep`. Since that I would use `sed` for a portable solution:

```
sed -n 's/.*\"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/p' <<< 'some stuff "A234DG3" maybe more stuff'
```

However, having GNU goodies, GNU `grep` will support PCRE expressions with the `-P` command line option. You can use this:

```
grep -oP '.*?"\K[^"]+(?=")' <<< 'some stuff "A234DG3" maybe more stuff'
```

`.*"` matches everything until the first quote - including it. The `\K` option clears the matching buffer and therefore works like a handy, dynamic lookbehind assertion. (I could have used a *real* lookbehind but I like `\K`). `[^"]+` matches the text between the quotes. `(?=")`  is a lookahead assertion the ensure after the match will follow a `"` - without including it into the match.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an RE is pretty much required to match the *longest* sequence it can. So, given something like:

```
a "bcd" efg "hij" klm "nop" q
```

A pattern of `".*"` should match: `"bcd" efg "hij" klm "nop"` (everything from the first quote to the last quote), not just `"bcd"`.

You probably want a pattern more like `"[^"]*"` to match the open-quote, an arbitrary number of other things, then a close quote.